# Smooth scrolling effect of Raphael Shapes

Tags: jquery, raphael, graphael

I am having diagram similar to g.rapahel http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html , i am storing shapes in the array like below code

```
var shapes = new Array();
var kx=50,ky=150;
var RecWidth=120;
var RecHeight=85;
var RecRadius=10;

r = Raphael(10,10, '60%', '100%');

for (var i=0; i<= 50; i++) {

 shapes[i]=r.rect(kx, ky, RecWidth, RecHeight,RecRadius);

 shapes[i].id="keylist"+i ;

 kx=kx+50;

 ky=ky+100;

}
```

Now suppose, i want to move shape[1] along with the window scroll with the connection line shown in graffle (above link).intention is that Shapes[1] (for simplicity, i am choosing this) should always there in the frame when scrolled. how to do this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var originalTop = shape[1].getBBox().y;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
        var dy = $(window).scrollTop();
        shape[1].animate({y: originalTop+y}, 300);
   });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But my shapes also 4 different Raphael Texts. I am trying to scroll these texts as well by putting these texts & shapes in Raphael set.it did animate but texts overlap on each other. is there any way we can achieve this with "set"  or is there any other way to do this? Also how to animate the connected lines in this case (as shown in above gRaphael link). i also want that lines should also come along with the shape and texts.

Comment: Thanks Diego for the base. I could make it work with "set" as well.